# MQTT Mosquitto SSL/TLS cannot connect with CA.der but can with CA.pem

Tags: ssl, openssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I have a simple question that I hope has a simple answer! I can connect and publish/subscribe to my broker using a Certificate Authority in `.pem` format. For example, the command:

```
mosquitto_pub --cafile CA.pem -h www.example.com -p 8883 -t test -u "usr" -p "pw"
```

is successful. However, when I convert `CA.pem` to `CA.der` using

```
openssl x509 -in CA.pem -out CA.der -outform DER
```

and use `CA.der` as the `--cafile` I get an error:

```
Unable to connect (A TLS error occurred.).
```

I believe the conversion is correct because if I convert `CA.der` back to `CA2.pem` using `openssl x509` I can successfully connect. My guess is that I have to set something in my `mosquitto.conf` file to allow `*.der`, or something similar, but cannot find anything that addresses this in the documentation, or anywhere online. I need to use the `.der` format because I am setting up an MQTT client on a TI CC3200 dev board, and TI's API requires all certs in `.der` format.

**Some additional information in case it's needed**

I got the CA for my domain through CertBot, and the certificate chain looks like this:

```
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = <www.example.com>
verify return:1
```

**mosquitto.conf**

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

listener 1883 localhost

listener 8883
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<www.example.com>/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<www.example.com>/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<www.example.com>/privkey.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

No, mosquitto only supports supplying certificates in PEM format, you can not use DER files.

There is nothing to say you have to use the same format (PEM/DER) of certificate storage on the broker side as on the client side.